# Duplicate rows in the database

Tags: php, mysql

We are having an issue where we have 5 dinner tables which are available for booking. The problem we have is that these tables are very popular and the users who wish to book these tables all try to book at the same time and occasionally the same table is being assigned twice. What would be the best way(fullproof) to stop this from happening?

The code is below

```
$date="2015-05-01 19:00";


// LIST OF DINNER TABLES
$fcas = array('Table 1','Table 2','Table 3','Table 4','Table 5');}


// FIND AVAILABLE DINNER TABLE
$sql = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE   date_time='$ed' and table_assigned IN ('" . implode("','", $fcas) . "'))";


$rs = mysql_query($sql);

if (!$rs) {
    // Handle query errors here
}

$rows = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {
    $rows[$row['table_assigned']] = $row;
}

foreach ($fcas as $fca) {
    if (!isset($rows[$fca])) {
        break;
    }
}


// INSERT RECORD

$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO bookings (date_time, table_assigned) VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($date)."', '".mysql_real_escape_string($fca)."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql_insert)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: That's a pretty scary way to be accessing your database.

Comment: `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. You should move to `mysqli_*` or, even better, use PDO to communicate with your database.

Comment: You should block / reserve a table for an x-amount of time as soon as someone starts to make a booking. Then free it up again if the reservation is not finished / confirmed within a certain amount of time.

Comment: Hi Jeroen, this is what we do but as they are all added at the exact same time it can cause duplication issues.

Comment: No, at the moment the visitor opens the booking page, you should already check and update your availability by blocking a table. Then there can be no duplication.

Comment: there is an ajax call to a separate page via a "Book" button. If many users click at the same it adds the row instantly

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use Transactions.

You need to read up about them!

You will basically attempt to reserve the table. The table will lock. The reservation will be attempted, if successful, proceed, and unlock.

So, whoever reserves first will have that table locked as long as it processes.

EDIT: some of the comments mention blocking the table as soon as a request for it begins. That's basically what Ticketmaster does for seating, you get a x amount of time to finish or the seat is released back into the pool of reservable tables.

Comment: The difference with what we do is that we assign Table 1 when the user clicks the add button and then Table 2 etc. the user does not actually select the dinner table they want.  When two users click at the exact same time it is possible(although rare) that when the check is done that both results return 0 so the script assigns the same table to two users.

Comment: That's exactly what transactions would prevent. You just need to change your script to use transactions. There is NO same time clicking, even with milliseconds, the system will take the first one first, and reject the 2nd, and you could assign it to the next available table.